# VBA Macros on two worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA object in Excel 2003 that triggers three simple macros when certain values are attained via streaming data.  It runs nicely.  I would like to open a duplicate worksheet, but with different streaming data, and have the macros trigger on their respective sheets.  It works now, but only on the worksheet I currently have selected.  Each worksheet has the object and macros in it.

The object monitors three cells, and when the first cell is triggered, goes on to monitor the next cell, and when triggered monitors the next cell, then repeats.

I would some help having them both run on their respective spreadsheets at the same time.

Here is the VBA object:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Static oldval1
Static oldval2
Static oldval3

Static LastAction As Integer
' Initial state will be 0, neither Fast nor Slow
Const Fast As Integer = 1
Const Fast2 As Integer = 2
Const Slow As Integer = 3

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Range("I1").Value = "1" And oldval1 <> "1" And LastAction <> Fast Then
  PasteFast
  LastAction = Fast
ElseIf Range("Q1").Value = "1" And oldval2 <> "1" And LastAction <> Slow Then
  PasteFast2
  LastAction = Fast2
ElseIf Range("Y1").Value = "1" And oldval3 <> "1" And LastAction <> Slow Then
  PasteSlow
  LastAction = Slow
End If

oldval1 = Range("I1").Value
oldval2 = Range("Q1").Value
oldval3 = Range("Y1").Value

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

And, here are the three macros – they are essentially the same – they copy from the same location, but paste into different locations. PasteSlow and PasteFast are on one module, and PasteFast2 is on a second module (for no reason).

```
Sub PasteSlow()
'
' PasteSlow Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("G5:G57").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("H5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("K5:K57").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("L5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub PasteFast()
'
' PasteFast Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("g5:g57").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("P5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("k5:k57").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("T5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub


Sub PasteFast2()
'
' PasteFast2 Macro
'

'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("g5:g57").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("x5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("k5:k57").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("ab5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I super-apologize for any code formatting errors.

Comment: Try opening it in a different Excel Instance?

Comment: VBA doesn't support multi-threading. So as @SiddharthRout suggested, either open the sheets in separate Excel instances, or perhaps have the macros take turns on which one is running.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your code isn't working lies in the way that you use the Range function.  Using Range alone is short for Application.Range.

The Excel help files say this about it:

> When used without an object qualifier, this property is a shortcut for ActiveSheet.Range (it returns a range from the active sheet; if the active sheet isn’t a worksheet, the property fails).

Keeping this in the `Worksheet_Calculate` event locks it to the given worksheet.

I would suggest moving the code that's in your `Worksheet_Calculate` into a module in a separate function with the cells of interest as parameters.  This would allow you DRY up your code, and allow you to place a call to the function in the `Worksheet_Activate` event.

If you don't want to rewrite the code, just throw a call to `Worksheet_Calculate` into the `Worksheet_Activate` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Worksheet_Calculate
End Sub
```

This will start your code upon entering the worksheet.